# Is it possible to replace JavaScript snippets on the fly through Firebug

Tags: firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to replace a line(s) of code from a JS file, through Firebug/Chrome DevTools.
I know it is possible to swap css classes. Is it possible with JS?

For example I know that this line is causing a JS error,

```
if(someVar.length == 10)
```

So I want to swap it with

```
if(someVar && someVar.length == 10)
```

My intention is to have a quick fix demo on the production server, before getting started with a bug fix.

Comment: I found a better solution, Fiddler. Not only is it browser agnostic, it allows me to intercept every HTTP request and modify the response on the fly, without requiring access to the host.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome DevTools supports this feature: [[1]](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#liveedit), [[2]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItMcQyXrWF8); it is called Live Edit there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
<sub>(source: [fidelitydesign.net](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Firebug-Testing.jpg))</sub>

You can use the Firebug Console tab to write Javascript.  I use this quite a lot of rapid prototyping of code before I integrate it into my projects. When you use the Console, javascript is executed in the context of the current page.  Therefore, and scripts that are currently defined for that page, can potentionally be redefind.  E.g., in the Console window, I could do this:

```
$ = function() { alert("Whoops"); }
```

...and that would redefine the `$` function used by JQuery.

Navigate to the Document Object Model viewing pane on the website's source code you want to modify.

Select the white space of any row in the tree and double-click on it.

Change the value of the variable through the editor that pops up following Step 1.

Update the value with static text, numbers or an equation.

Write a command line JavaScript expression for what you want to include in place of a static constant. Press "Enter" and the command line is evaluated and the result is displayed for the variable.

Use the Auto Complete function by hitting the Tab key to move forward through object properties in the source code. Continue to tab through all the options and press "Shift-Tab" to go backwards in the code.

View your changes immediately in the top website pane. Continue to make changes until you are satisfied with how the website displays.

You can use Firerbug to write and execute a JavaScript in realtime. This is a good way to test and make sure that the script is working properly before you deploy it in a production environment.

Open Firebug and write a code as shown. Press enter. Immediately you will see the output of the code.

[image]